# How do I do I select multiple files?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, file-io

I need to select multiple files from the browse button. Right now, my code only selects one file. I need to select multiple files (by pressing control on Windows or command on Mac) and process them individually.I want a file per each line in my textbox.

Comment: [Microsoft's OpenFileDialog documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_OpenFileDialog_Multiselect) has a pretty solid example of doing exactly that.

Comment: Sometimes it's worth just having a quick flick through the docs for the control in question. In this case, there are only 6 properties, one of which is [`Multiselect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening multiple files (OpenFileDialog, C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311578/opening-multiple-files-openfiledialog-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenFileDialog has a Multiselect property.

Add this into your code(before showing the dialog).

```
fd.Multiselect = true;
```